# Adding a string to a listbox from textbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio

thanks for your help, I have a listbox where I am inserting a string, however when I select that new line I receive the following error:
System.InvalidCastException: 'No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo 'System.String' al tipo 'TESTLSD.Registro'.'
This is my code:

```
private void btnNuevoRegistro_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   if (txtNuevoRegistro.Text.Length > 0)
    {
      lstLSD.Items.Insert(lstLSD.SelectedIndex + 1, Convert.ToString(txtNuevoRegistro.Text));
                txtNuevoRegistro.Clear();
    }
    else MessageBox.Show("No hay registro para adicionar");

 }

And
```

this is my SelectedIndexChange

```
private void lstLSD_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     if (this.lstLSD.SelectedIndex != -1)
       {
         registroSeleccionado = (Registro)this.lstLSD.SelectedItem;
         label2.Text = "Registro " + registroSeleccionado;
         string item = lstLSD.SelectedItem.ToString();
         if (item.StartsWith("01")) { button1.Enabled = true; } else { button1.Enabled = false; };
         if (item.StartsWith("02")) { button3.Enabled = true; } else { button3.Enabled = false; };
         if (item.StartsWith("03")) { button4.Enabled = true; } else { button4.Enabled = false; };
         if (item.StartsWith("04")) { button5.Enabled = true; } else { button5.Enabled = false; };
       }
  }
```

Any idea so I can select this line after adding it? THANKS!

Comment: which line gives the error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume its this line thats failing

```
registroSeleccionado = (Registro)this.lstLSD.SelectedItem;
```

you are trying to cast a string to so you can assign it to registroSeleccionado which I assume is of type TESTLSD.Registro

You are trying to cast a string to it, that wont work. What is the relationship between that string and that class. If you had the class instance origially try setting the ListItem.Tag to that instance,